# Constructor in C++ Class

Tags: c++

I have two Classes, Player and Game.

```
class Game
{
        private:
            int maxPlayer;
            Player** playersArray;
        public:
            Game(int maxPlayer);
            ~Game();
}
```

Each index in playersArray consists of pointers to class Player.The following constructor doesn't work, since this message keeps appearing:

```
error: invalid use of 'Player::Player' playersArray[i]->Player();
Game::Game(int maxPlayer)
{   this->maxPlayer=maxPlayer;
    this->playersArray = new Player*[maxPlayer];
    for(int i=0;i<maxPlayer;i++)
    {
        playersArray[i]->Player();
    }
}
```

This is the class Player:

```
class Player {
        private:
            char* player_name;
            int level;
            int life;
            int strength;
            Weapon player_weapon;
            int place; 
}
```

My aim is to set the player_name to NULL and *NOT* to a random place in the memory. This is what Player() is supposed to do.

Comment: You should never call constructor directly.

Comment: What can I do in this case?

Comment: `playersArray[i] = new Player;`

Comment: You should use vector of smart pointers

Comment: Already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750773/classes-in-c-constructor-and-dtor

Comment: @Slava unless you are using placement new (: ?

Comment: @SamerTufail when you use placement new you still do not call ctor directly, new does it for you.

Comment: @Slava not really `new(buffer) T()` where buffer points to where T() should be constructed followed by a explicit call to the ctor.

Comment: @SamerTufail where do you see explicit call to constructor here? Explicit call to ctor whould be `new(buffer)->T()` or `new(buffer) T->T();`

Comment: @Slava I misunderstood (: - backing off now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classes in C++ Constructor and D'tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750773/classes-in-c-constructor-and-dtor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not populating your `Game` array correctly.  You are trying to call the `Player()` constructor as if it were a regular class method (which it is not), and worse you are calling it via an *uninitialized* `Player*` pointer.

You need to use the `new` operator instead, eg:

```
class Game
{
private:
    int maxPlayers;
    Player** playersArray;
public:
    Game(int aMaxPlayers);
    ~Game();
}

Game::Game(int aMaxPlayers)
{
    maxPlayers = aMaxPlayers;
    playersArray = new Player*[maxPlayers];
    for(int i = 0; i < maxPlayers; ++i)
        playersArray[i] = new Player; // <-- here
}

Game::~Game()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < maxPlayers; ++i)
        delete playersArray[i];
    delete[] playersArray;
}
```

A safer option is to use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers:

```
#include <memory>

class Game
{
private:
    int maxPlayers;
    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<Player>[]> playersArray;
public:
    Game(int aMaxPlayers);
}

Game::Game(int aMaxPlayers)
{
    maxPlayers = aMaxPlayers;
    playersArray = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<Player>[]>(maxPlayers);
    for(int i = 0; i < maxPlayers; ++i)
        playersArray[i] = std::make_unique<Player>();
}
```

That being said, there is no need to use an array of `Player*` pointers when an array of `Player` objects will suffice instead:

```
class Game
{
private:
    int maxPlayers;
    Player* playersArray;
public:
    Game(int aMaxPlayers);
    ~Game();
}

Game::Game(int aMaxPlayers)
{
    maxPlayers = aMaxPlayers;
    playersArray = new Player[maxPlayers];
}

Game::~Game()
{
    delete[] playersArray;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <memory>

class Game
{
private:
    int maxPlayers;
    std::unique_ptr<Player[]> playersArray;
public:
    Game(int aMaxPlayers);
}

Game::Game(int aMaxPlayers)
{
    maxPlayers = aMaxPlayers;
    playersArray = std::make_unique<Player[]>(maxPlayers);
}
```

Which you can then simplify further by using `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>

class Game
{
private:
    std::vector<Player> playersArray;
public:
    Game(int maxPlayers);
}

Game::Game(int maxPlayers)
    : playersArray(maxPlayers)
{
}
```